# Analyzing trend of proportions

Tags: r, percentage, trend

I am analyzing data of antimicrobial resistance of a microorganism. I want to see if the resistance (Y/N) change over a period of time (year 2010-2017). I am using a logistic regression model, and code in R like this:

```r
model1 = glm(tetM ~ year, 
             data=dat2,
             family = binomial)
```

Is this OK? Am I on the right track? And I got a summary of the model like this:

summary(model1)

```
Call:
glm(formula = tetM ~ year, family = binomial, data = dat2)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.6557   0.2444   0.4391   0.5003   1.4823  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -0.6931     0.7071  -0.980 0.326959    
year2011      1.9459     1.0690   1.820 0.068724 .  
year2012      2.6391     0.8864   2.977 0.002908 ** 
year2013      2.7081     1.0328   2.622 0.008740 ** 
year2014      3.0350     0.8481   3.579 0.000345 ***
year2015      2.9339     0.8493   3.455 0.000551 ***
year2016      1.9459     0.9063   2.147 0.031791 *  
year2017      4.1897     1.2371   3.387 0.000707 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 173.74  on 227  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 152.32  on 220  degrees of freedom
AIC: 168.32

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6
```

Am I right if I conclude that there is a significant increasing trend of resistance?

Answer (score 0):

The table is very hard to read you should use the reprex function of the reprex's library.
But since the coefficient are significant and that they are crescent over time I would go with the same conclusion.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Is this a coding question (suitable for this site) or a statistics question.  If the later consider posting this question on CrossValidated https://stats.stackexchange.com. Check out [ask] for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, is your variable "year" a data frame containing other columns like, 2015...2017? If it does, is it each one measured by days (or months, semester, etc), like: variable 2017 containing day 1, ... , day 365. Because if it is expressed like that, the significance will tell you that the more days, the more resistance. But if your variable "year" has only 7 values, like 2015,2016, ... , 2017, you should not get any conclusion from that. It's a very short number of variables given to the model, the estimations are not quite reliable.

However, if you want to analyse if the resistance changes by the year. I recommend you to search about non-parametric Mcnemar hypothesis test.

Comment: My variable 'year' has 8 values; 2010 - 2017. Each year has many records of resistance ranged from 10 to 52. Should I really go for a non-parametric analysis?

Comment: Nice. If you have over 50 observations for each variable, the significance level of the coefficients can been taken. Though, the Mcnemar test will act on the output value, it's not necessary, but would give you a more robust analyse.